# Invalid Image message from post api while uploading file using robot framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to upload image file using robot framework post request but getting invalid image error message after execution.

**Code Snippet**

```
    Create Session      imageupload     http://httpbin.org
    ${headers}=         Create Dictionary     Content-Type=multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryJlIb5JIA0vGUnjmb
    ${my_id}=           Set Variable              ${StudentId}
    ${params} =          Create Dictionary        key_id=Keyinformation   
    ${filepath}=        Get Binary File      c:\User\image.png
    ${file}=             Evaluate     base64.b64encode($filepath)       modules=base64
    ${base86Image}=      Create Dictionary       KeyUploadImage=${file}

    ${URI}=            Set Variable    /my_id/
    ${response}=        Post Request    imageupload     ${URI}   data=${base86Image}    params=${params}        timeout=5
    Log To Console      ${response}
```

Response:

```
20170814 15:47:23.854 : DEBUG : post response: {"error":"INVALID_IMAGE"}
20170814 15:47:23.934 : INFO : Post Request using : alias=imageupload       , uri=/my_id/, data=<empty>, headers=None, files={u'file': '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02N\x00\x00\x01\xba\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xfe\xb2\xc9g\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f\x0b\xfca\x05\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x01\xc7o\xa8d\x00\x00\xff\xa5IDATx^\xec\xfdg\x98$\xc7\x95\xae\t\xf2\xef\xfe\xda}fw\xef\xcc\xdc\xdd\x9d\xd9\xee{\xb7u7\x9b\n$\x01Bk\x8d\x02PU@Ak\xad\xb5V$\x14\t\x90\x00\xb5n\xb2)@\x01\x90\x84\x16\x84*\x9d:32D\x86\xcaH\xadK\xeb\x02\x88\xb3\xdfw\xcc\x8f\x87\x85\x87EfdV\x15\xd8\xddD=xa\xeef\xe6\xe6""\xdd\xde037\xff\x98|\xf4\xef\xa3\x7f\x1f\xfd\xfb\xe8\xdfG\xff>\xfa\xf7\xd1\xbf\x8f\xfe}\xf4\xaf\xa9\x7f\x1f\x89\xd3G\xff>\xfa\xf7\xd1\xbf\x8f\xfe}\xf4\xef\xa3\x7f\x1f\xfd\xfb\xe8_\x93\xff>\xb6\xba\xb5M\xd6\xb4\xb5+k\xdb;\xa4\xa5\xa3Si\xed\xec\xd2u\x8b\xe3z[W\xb7t\xf4\xa4\xa4#\xd5+\x1d\xbd\xbd\xd2\x99A\x98E\x98KKw.#= \xd5\x97U\xd2\xf9\x9cd\xf2}\x92\xf3\xe9\x8b\xc0r\xb6\x90\xffP\xc9\x80t\xa1\xa0\xf4\xe6\xf38\xd6\x9ctg\xb3\xd2\x95\xc9(<\x1f\xd2\x9eJ\xc5\xb4\xf5\xf4H[w\x8f\xb4v\xf5Fd\xa4\xa53\xed\x91RZ\xbb\x08\xf2uw\xd7\x83k\xd7\xd6^K{G\x97\xc2\xe5\xd6\xb6\x8e\x1aZZ\xdb\xabD\xd7}\xdeh\xd9\xdd1\xed\x1d=J\x1b\x8e\xb5\r\xc7\xda\xde\x8ds\xedI;R8w\xd0\xd9\x9bU\xba\xd2\xd5kBx\x8d\x08\xaf\x17I\xe1\xf3#\xbc\x86\xbc\x96\x99bQ\xb2\xa5\x92d\xca\xa0\xbf,i\xc00[\xe9w`9Wv\xe4\xcb\xfdJ\xa1\xbf"\xc5rEJ\xa0X\xeao\x08\xd3I\xa1X\x0e\x92\x07}%\x802\xfb\xfa\x1b\x93\xafT\xea\xe2x<}VN\xa1$}\xf9"\xbe\x9b\x05\xc9\xe6\xf0]\xc9\xf6I:\x93\xab\xa1\x17\xd7\x85\xa4z\xf1\x1d\'\xb8v)\\G\xa3\x07\xd7\xd5\xe8\xee\xeciH\x17\xbe\']\xdd)\xa5\xbb\x07\xdb\xa5P\x0e\xcac\xd9\xdc\x0f\x8f\x83\xc7Cxlv-\n\x80\xe7\x9a#\xd1\xf5\xdc\x9b\xf0\x1a5"\x94\xdf\'ym\x9b%TV\x15\xe4)\x0f\xe0|\xb1\x7f\x8fP\\\x1d\xd1\xf7!Yfr\xff\x0b\xc1\xaeIa`@\x89\xaf\x13\xbe\xd3\xf9\xfe\xc1\x86\xf0\xb8\xfd\xf5BeH)\x0e\x0c\xa3\x1c\xacG\xe5\x19\xc5\xc1\xc1\xa6\xf0\xf3\x97\x86\x86\x14?\xdd\xe2B\x94\x87F\x17DipdVB\xdb\x18u\xc70<\xdc<\x81\xf2\x9a\xa1\x04\x8a\xc3\x <truncated>
20170814 15:47:23.961 : INFO : C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:858: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
20170814 15:47:23.961 : INFO : ${response} = <Response [400]>
20170814 15:47:23.963 : INFO : ${response} = <Response [400]>
```

Comment: Is it related to python or specific to robot framework. I stuck due to this error.

Comment: Did some R&D ,INVALID_IMAGE indicates corrupted image.   I guess Get Binary File keyword creating problem but if i use Get File keyword in that case i am getting ' 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte' error. Any comment from experts.

Comment: It's Resolved..